# Как усовершенствовать владение языком?

Tags: обучение

Скажите, как лучше усовершенствовать свой русский и писать в идеале самостоятельно?

Comment: Кстати, мне этот форум очень помогает совершенствовать грамотность. 

Answer (score 4):

Есть один способ,описанный в "Комсомольской правде".Девушка на экзамене в университет получила 2 по русскому языку, а по остальным предметам - 5. Профессор, председатель комиссии, сказал, что берёт её кандидатом при условии, что она за год перепишет "Войну и мир" Толстого, сдавая ему лично переписанные тетради. Поначалу плакала от злости и от непонимания смысла этой работы, но ежемесячно приносила ему толстые тетради. Он прятал их в стол, не читая. К концу года эта студентка стала самой грамотной на курсе. Древние говорили:"Пишущий дважды читает". У Толстого нет ошибок.Были задействованы 2 вида памяти - зрительная и моторная. Рука сама запомнила написание многократно повторенных слов. 
Если очень хочется и Вы готовы на такой подвиг - вперёд! Успехов в хорошем деле!

Answer (score 3):

На Грамоте есть [раздел с диктантами](http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/idictation/) — весьма полезная вещь для тех, кто хочет развивать и совершенствовать свою грамотность )

Answer (score 2):

Память, ёмкая, как гроссбух, и бесплодные попытки просто заучить нужные слова и правила скорее вредят, чем приносят пользу. Чтобы писать грамотно, надо либо обладать врождённой грамотностью (благодаря языковой интуции получить все необходимые, впоследствии неосознаваемые знания из чтения), либо понимать природу языка вообще и принципы литературной нормы, орфографии, пунктуации и стилистики в частности. К сожалению, последнее приходится осуществлять самостоятельно — почти все справочники и почти (?) вся школьная программа рассчитана на идиотов-мнематиков, которые могут заучить огромное количество правил, но не могут их осмыслить и как-то между собой увязать. Зато такое понимание влечёт за собой расширение кругозора, лёгкость в изучении многих нужных Вам языковых феноменов и прочие плюшки.
Удачи в изучении литературной нормы!

Answer (score 2):

Читать, читать и читать. По-моему, это единственный разумный способ повысить грамотность. Кстати, такого явления как врожденная грамотность не существует)) Грамотность может быть только приобретенной и никак иначе. Обычно именно начитанность и дает то, что называют врожденной грамотностью — работает зрительная память, многое откладывается без заучивания правил.

В общем, рекомендую читать. Желательно, конечно, хорошую литературу. Хотя вот диктанты на Грамоте.ру — тоже хорошо

Answer (score 2):

"Читайте словари, как художественную литературу!" - любимое выражение моей бывшей учительницы. И моё тоже.

Answer (score 2):

А зачем нам вообще правила? Давайте их отменим, и попробуем грамотно писать без правил. Практически всю орфографию составляют две большие темы: буквенная орфография и форма написания слов и словосочетаний. Слово состоит из 4-морфем, вот и пишите каждую морфему по очереди. У нас всего-то около 40 приставок, около сотни проблемных суффиксов и немного окончаний (два спряжения глаголов и три склонения существительных). Ну еще корни добавьте (проверяемые, непроверяемые, немного чередующихся).
Слова пишите преимущественно слитно, словосочетания - раздельно. Дефисная форма - промежуточная (уже не слово, но еще не словосочетание). Где тут правила? Здесь одна грамматика. Ну и об основном принципе русского письма не забывайте: фонетическое чередование звуков не отражается на письме (наше письмо фонематическое, то есть смысловое, а не звуковое).

Answer (score 1):

Если терпения хватит - тупо проверять каждое предложение при помощи Розенталя и словаря. Когда-нибудь все запомните, когда надоест каждый раз лазить.

Answer (score 1):

Самый рациональный способ, на мой взгляд, предложил knes. Не нужно переписывать "Войну и мир" - читайте литературу, которую считаете интересной и полезной, и по ходу чтения анализируйте орфографию и пунктуацию, в сомнительных для Вас случаях развевая свои сомнения с помощью словарей и справочников. То же касается и текстов собственного сочинения. Это утомительная (хоть и не настолько, как, например, последовательное изучение правил) и отнимающая много времени работа, но изучение языка - даже родного! - для человека со среднестатистическими психологическими показателями и интеллектуальными способностями, увы, не может быть безболезненным процессом.
P. S. Не соглашусь со мнением о диктантах на Грамоте как о хорошем способе улучшить знание орфографии и пунктуации: в диктантах масса ошибок, кроме того их цель - устранение пробелов в знании самых базовых пунктограмм и орфограмм, трудностей в усвоении которых, как правило, не возникает. Поэтому способ, может, и неплохой, но абсолютной грамотности он Вам не обеспечит.