# Проблема с русским языком!

Tags: орфография

Дорогие читатели! Я понимаю, что на данном форуме не обсуждаются психологические вопросы. Но я очень прошу мне помочь. С начала лета я решил, что мне следует выучить русский язык на хорошем уровне, а затем просто перейти к немецкому языку. Задача была поставлена, и я начал. Для достижения цели я читал вот этот учебник (http://www.alleng.ru/d/rusl/rusl342.htm), который, кстати, уже читал два раза. Просто тогда я читал не очень-то и внимательно... Недавно, несколько дней назад, я осознал, что у меня ничего не получается. Я вечно начинаю его перечитывать. Дойду до пятидесятой страницы - начинаю перечитывать. В последнее время сложно спать из-за этого. Когда я засыпаю, я постоянно думаю, почему пишется так, а не иначе. Я просто уже не могу. Мысли возникают даже о суициде. Добрые люди, помогите мне, пожалуйста! Я уже просто не могу.

Благодарю всех, кто прочитал.

Постскриптум: я за это время его раз десять пробовал перечитывать. Я постоянно, идя по улице, начинаю думать о разных словах. И когда не нахожу правильного ответа, то сразу же начинаю беситься. Факт потраченного времени также меня вывод из себя. Если что, я перешел в восьмой класс.

Comment: Полноте, Tagirix! Для своего возраста вы знаете язык очень неплохо. А всего на свете не знает никто. Совершенство, увы, не достижимо. Попробуйте перестать предъявлять к себе непомерно высокие требования. У Вас даже до ГИА ещё море времени!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас проблема не с русским языком. Образно говоря: Вы поставили себе задачу - поднять штангу весом 200 кГ. Все Ваши мысли вертятся вокруг этой цифры. Вы пытаетесь эту штангу поднять, но - не получается (и не получится!). Нужна кропотливая ежедневная работа, тренировка. Начинать надо не сразу с 200-от, а - первый вес: сколько удаётся поднять. Переход от удачи к удаче и есть решение проблемы. Но штангисту проще бороться с самим собою. Ваша проблема не имеет ярко выраженного количественного измерения. Тем не менее!.. Что касается суицида. Это возрастная болезнь. Надо не замыкаться на самом себе, а смотреть вокруг. Лучше всего обратить внимание на окружающих девочек (идеализировать одну из них, Её, и влюбиться!). О-о-чень отвлекает от дурных мыслей! И помогает в достижении успеха для решения поставленной задачи.

Comment: Ищите и - обрящете!

Answer (score 3):

Мне приходилось работать репетитором, и я могу сказать, что первый шаг - это диагностика. Ученик  пишет орфографический диктант средней сложности, после проверки которого обсуждаются ошибки. После этого можно поставить "диагноз", то есть определить темы, которые вызывают трудности, которые не усвоены, не поняты. Вот с ними и надо работать. Напишите такой диктант, сверьте его с оригиналом, подумайте над ошибками и присылайте пакет вопросов. Откроем онлайн-тему "Я пишу диктант".

Answer (score 3):

Сперва по русскому языку. А что вы понимаете под "хорошо знать язык"? Чтобы быть хорошим оратором и писателем вовсе не обязательно писать без ошибок, а письмо без ошибок не гарантирует того, что ваш текст будет удобочитаемым. Определитесь чего вы хотите добиться от изучения языка, и уже после этого подбирайте под цель подходящую программу. Одно дело если вы хотите стать филологом, другое если просто сдать ЕГЭ (ГИА) на достойную оценку.

Теперь по поводу "мыслей о самоубийстве". Это частое явление  в вашем возрасте, только вот воплощать их в реальность не нужно. Чтобы избавиться от депрессии, можно выразить свои переживания в творчестве (рисунок, стихи, музыка и т. п.) или обратиться к психологу. Мне в свое время из помогла как раз "стихотворная терапия", и застрелившийся лирический герой вывел из депрессии меня. Правда по прошествии лет я жалею, что не обратился к психотерапевту, так как за время "самолечения" я успел натворить немало ошибок, негативно отразившихся на моей жизни.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что данная проблема связана с изучением любой новой науки: трудно представить, что за короткий срок мы сможем освоить что-то в совершенстве, поэтому не стоит даже ставить таких задач (это  психологически вредно). Можно поставить задачу  достигнуть определенного уровня и далее совершенствовать свои знания также постепенно. В этом случае достижение каждого уровня будет вызывать положительные эмоции, так важно сказать себе: «Какой же я молодец!»

И здесь возникает проблема, связанная с русским языком. Как и всякий язык, это целый мир, состоящий из нескольких разделов: грамматика, фонетика, лексика, орфография, пунктуация. И каждый раздел нужно также осваивать по уровням.

Важной задачей является выбор подходящего учебника, так как каждая книга имеет своего адресата.  И уж в любом случае не следует сразу читать специализированные авторские монографии, рассчитанные на совершенствование уже имеющихся знаний.

В Вашем случае важно не углубляться  сразу в частные проблемы, а видеть  каждую тему целиком,  окинуть ее взглядом сверху, а затем  приступать к изучению входящих в нее структур. Таким образом, всякий раз вы будете знать, где вы находитесь, насколько важно для Вас  изучить это  именно сейчас.

Мне кажется, неплохими вариантом в этом случае являются учебные пособия для подготовки к ЕГЭ. Там в сжатом виде повторяется весь курс языка. Можно одну и ту же тему посмотреть в разных учебниках, сравнить, сделать собственный вывод. Любая исследовательская работа очень полезна и психологически, и с точки зрения усвоения знаний.

Comment: Понимаете, что я уже не могу просто. Вы можете как-нибудь мне помочь?

Answer (score 1):

Главное, не переживайте. Всегда и во всем сначала кажется, что ничего не получается. А потом - раз! - и понимаешь, что знания-то есть!
Но Вам, во-первых, нужно определиться с тем, как Вам лучше воспринимать информацию: в виде правил или в виде образов, а то и на слух. Уверена, что для всех способов есть свои пособия.
Во-вторых, побольше пишите, и количество перейдет в качество.
А еще - читайте этот форум, спрашивайте. Мне, например, это сильно помогло.

Answer (score 0):

Есть очень хорошая книжка(вы, наверное, знаете: красного цвета книжка) по орфографии и пунктуации. Д.Э.Розенталь, И.Б.Голубь. Домашний репетитор.И еще одна хорошая книга. Русский язык. Весь курс. Для выпускников и абитуриентов. И.Б. Голубь. И как сказала София, присылайте неясные вопросы сюда. Вам помогут. Кстати, для восьмого класса пишите очень хорошо!!!

Comment: Вот Вы пишете : *красного цвета книжка*. Мне это напомнило галустяновское: *букварь и синюю*)))

Comment: Правильно: Голуб.

Answer (score 0):

Не  надо  "читать"  учебник.  Надо  медленно,  но  верно  усваивать  его  положения.  Понял,  усвоил,  отрепетировал - переходи  к  следующему.  Не  можешь  сам - ищи  учителя.  Может  всё  дело  в  методике.    И,  как  пишет  Марк Из,  с  задачей  надо  определиться.

Answer (score 0):

А в чем вопрос?
Думаете о словах - ну и думайте себе на здоровье. Я тоже о них часто думаю. 
Перечитывать учебник каждый раз - не надо. Если Вы не можете усвоить написанное, значит учебник вам не подходит или Вы неправильно им пользуетесь.
Язык - не математика, его невозможно учить "от  сих до сих". От  того, что вы постоянно зубрите одно и тоже - толку мало. Может , лучше пропустить, перейти к другой теме? Вернуться-то никогда не поздно.
Остальное - индивидуально.

Answer (score 0):

Замечено, что изучение иностранного языка способствует лучшему овладению родным, позволяя как бы взглянуть на последний со стороны. Так что вовсе не обязательно строго воздерживаться от изучения немецкого языка. Одно другому не мешает.

Но может быть, "беситесь" Вы, потому что переутомились? Учёба - это тяжкий труд, а каникулы вообще-то предназначены для отдыха...

Answer (score 0):

@Tagirix, не сходите с ума. Прежде всего, никаких учебников читать не нужно, учить наизусть — тем более (если только Вы не собираетесь правила из него стоя на табуретке декламировать). Чтобы достичь успеха в изучении языка, нужно задаться целью привести в соответствие с языковыми нормами текст собственного сочинения. Как можно больше пользуйтесь письменной речью. Оставляйте сообщения на форумах, комментарии на YouTube, пишите длинные письма друзьям, обращаясь к словарям и справочникам по мере возникновения сомнений относительно соответствия речи нормам литературного языка. Предлагаю Вашему вниманию избранные наименования из моей библиотеки:
[Gramma.ru](http://gramma.ru/?PHPSESSID=27c3ae05b676d5e0ee9482dbe4a85dbf); 
[Gramota.ru](http://www.gramota.ru/);
[Грамматический справочник по русскому языку](http://www.orfo.ru/Tutorial/Html/Tutorial.htm); 
[Национальный корпус русского языка](http://ruscorpora.ru/);
[Валгина Н.С., Светлышева В.Н. Орфография и пунктуация](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/topicsw.htm);
[Мильчин А. Э., Чельцова Л. К. Справочник издателя и автора](http://diamondsteel.ru/useful/handbook/);
[Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник / Под ред. В.В. Лопатина](http://orthographia.ru/);
[Розенталь Д.Э. Прописная или строчная? Словарь-справочник](http://genling.ru/books/item/f00/s00/z0000027/index.shtml);
[Розенталь Д.Э. Справочник по правописанию, произношению, литературному редактированию](http://evartist.narod.ru/text1/20.htm);
[Балашова Л.В., Дементьев В.В. Курс русского языка](http://www.licey.net/russian/map);
[Русский язык](http://www.lingvotech.com/russianlang);
[Валгина Н.С. Розенталь Д.Э. Фомина М.И. Современный русский язык](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook107/01/topicsw.htm);
[Голуб И.Б. Стилистика русского языка](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook028/01/topicsw.htm);
[ЯРУС](http://yarus.aspu.ru/).

Об особенностях управления и согласования в русском языке, о нормах лексической сочетаемости Вы можете узнать из соответствующих словарей, которые в ассортименте доступны [здесь](http://dic.academic.ru).

Браузеры и текстовые редакторы с функцией автоматической проверки правописания помогут Вам запомнить словарные слова.

Для развлечения можете проверить свои знания с помощью интерактивных диктантов на сайтах, ссылки на которые я Вам дала.

Не представляете, что писать? Проанализируйте орфографию и пунктуацию в текстах, которые читаете. Например, Вам непонятно, почему я не выделила запятыми причастный оборот «стоя на табуретке» . Пусть желание выяснить это, а не осознанная необходимость выдолбить правило неизвестно для каких причин, станет поводом обратиться к справочной литературе. И да не окажетесь Вы во власти суицидальных мыслей, если какие-то из предложенных там орфографических и пунктуационных формул станут доступными для применения не сразу.  Когда-то для меня было серьезной проблемой определить, необходимо обособлять тот или иной оборот с союзом «как» или нет. Знаний с тех пор не прибавилось, но я почему-то  начала чувствовать разницу, которая доселе оставалась для меня незаметной.

Могу также предложить Вам ознакомиться с [данной](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/11090/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=26412#26412) и [настоящей](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/30727/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B0?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=30737#30737) темами.

И можете быть уверены, я Вам отходов не посоветую — личный опыт показал, что это вовсе не отходы.